# youtube upload widget category & tags

Tags: youtube-api

except for:

```
widget.setVideoTitle(title);
widget.setVideoDescription(description); 
widget.setVideoKeywords(keyword1, keyword2, ..., keywordn);
widget.setVideoPrivacy(privacy);
```

is there also a possibility to set Category and Tags along the vid upload???

cheerz!

Answer (score 0):

from the widget I think not, only the properties that you mentioned and in onApiReady:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_upload_widget#onApiReady

This event fires when the internal command API, which enables you to set metadata for a newly uploaded video, is ready. The event handler for this event can call the following functions to set metadata for an uploaded video:

widget.setVideoTitle(title) – The title parameter is a string that specifies the video title.

widget.setVideoDescription(description); – The description parameter is a string that specifies the video description.

widget.setVideoKeywords(keyword1, keyword2, ..., keywordn); – The function takes a list of string parameters, each of which specifies a keyword for the video.

widget.setVideoPrivacy(privacy) – The privacy parameter is a string that specifies the initial privacy setting for the newly uploaded video. Valid values are public, unlisted, and private. The default setting is public.